# Fire a Function on window close

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

I have a java script countdown timer on my page and i want to trigger an alert message if user tries to close the window or a tab.

Comment: [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Update: this answer was provided by Adnan in comment few mins before me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this event

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   //your message goes here
}
```

By using jQuery

```
$(window).unbind("beforeunload");
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function (e) {
   //do your work here
});
```